# Mobile device detection issue

Tags: mobile, detect

Today I added code to my websites head section to detect mobile device via screen size, code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 699) {document.location = "http://m.mywebsite.com";}
</script>
```

It works great for me, but the problem now is when I am redirected to mobile version of website, I got there link to go to desktop version of site. When I hit it, I am redirected to desktop version and then immediately redirected back to mobile site, for the reason I have mobile website detection! :-) it is endless circle. How to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to set a cookie of some sort to check that you clicked the link to view the full website. Why are you doing that like this by the way.. and not via .htaccess or php headers?

Comment: the only reason that I am using js is that I think it is the easiest way, isnt that right?

Comment: It might be the easiest way but it is not the best (for SEO and performance)

Comment: so what you say is that I will NOT overcome that problem with javascript method?

Comment: No you can.. but you have to set a cookie or something so you can check to you want to load the full site. This will prevent the looping.

Answer (score 0):

Size of the screen is probably not the best way to detect a mobile device. Take a look at http://wurfl.io/ and see if that is useful. 
And yes, you need a cookie or some local storage to avoid the looping

Answer (score 0):

Relying on screen size alone is not enough. In fact many modern smartphones have screens of well over 800 pixels wide. And then you also have tablets, smart TVs, consoles and e-readers. The best thing to do is use an existing solution like [51Degrees.com](http://51degrees.com/).

It’s easy to set up and the database is updated with new devices on regular basis. Detection is done on your server, which improves page-loading times for your users. Additionally you can use the [image optimiser](http://51degrees.com/Support/Documentation/PHP/Image-Optimiser) to handle image resizing when you redirect to mobile page.

For an easy, 4-step setup of PHP detector visit: [PHP Getting Started](http://51degrees.com/Support/Documentation/PHP/Getting-Started).